# Display contacts name and phone number in multiautocomplete textview

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist

I have a multiautocomplete textview which autocompletes when the user types something on the box with respect to the data query on the ContactsContracts using content resolver. But i wanted to display the name and number on one list.

here is the code

```
        name_Val = (String[]) c_Name.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
        phone_Val= (String[]) c_Number.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]); 


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_dropdown, name_Val);
        txtPhoneNo.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
        txtPhoneNo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Unfortunately it only displays the name. I wanted to display the number after the the contacts name.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the custom adapter or a simple adapter with custom view

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to improve your answer adding more details or examples. Such a brief answer seems not be useful for original poster and community.